# Inserting a variable inside weather app link using Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am using a weather app API to create a weather application.
I was able to reach the point that I could've print the weather if I hard coded the country in the link given.
My aim was to :
1 - Print the value of the city when I write it in the input and take the value and insert it in the link.
2 - unfortunately I couldn't do that [the point i reached is that I could get the input, but it won't accept it in the link]

Hint: I am a React beginner and trying my best to make my code work and using the DRY principle.

I appreciate your time and could use your help here.
Thanks in advance.

```
//Importing
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
//syntax

let inputValue = "";
console.log(" input value before updated", inputValue);
export default class main extends Component {
  state = {
    showList: false,
    data: "",
    temp: "",
    feels_like: "",
    humidity: "",
    pressure: "",
    name: "",
    country: "",
    description: "",
    icon: "",
    weather: "",
  };
  //Component Did mount

  handleInput = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      data: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  submitted = () => {
    inputValue = this.state.data;
    const show = this.state.showList;
    this.setState({ showList: !show });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${inputValue},uk&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          temp: response.data.main.temp,
          feels_like: response.data.main.feels_like,
          humidity: response.data.main.humidity,
          pressure: response.data.main.pressure,
          name: response.data.name,
          country: response.data.sys.country,
          description: response.data.weather[0].description,
          icon: response.data.weather[0].icon,
          weather: response.data.weather[0].main,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    let feels_like = this.state.feels_like;
    let temp = this.state.temp;
    let humidity = this.state.humidity;
    let pressure = this.state.pressure;
    let name = this.state.name;
    let country = this.state.country;
    let description = this.state.description;
    let icon = this.state.icon;
    let weather = this.state.weather;
    let list = null;
    if (this.state.showList) {
      list = (
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
          <h1>{feels_like}</h1>
          <h1>{temp}</h1>
          <h1>{humidity}</h1>
          <h1>{pressure}</h1>
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <h1>{country}</h1>
          <h1>{description}</h1>
          <img
            alt=""
            src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`}
          ></img>
          <h1>{weather}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleInput}
          typw="text"
          placeholder="Enter a country name"
        />
        <button onClick={this.submitted}>Search</button>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Extra Info:

```
.get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${inputValue},uk&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
      )
```

This is the part where I got 404 since it is not accepting the `${inputValue}`

Comment: Solved it in two ways. 1 - I merged them under one function so I deleted the component did mount. 2 - I was mistaken by keeping the UK so whenever I insert a value for example Tokyo it will be Tokyo, UK which doesn't exist. But I am open to keep component did mount so if you have any suggestions to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the inputValue part of the state. There is no reason to keep it as a global variable outside of the component like that.